# Switch from ip address to domain name in Apache httpd (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos7

I'm trying to access the web from client by domain name using httpd. I'm already set up DNS server and Httpd, the result is root can access by domain name right now. Now is only the client, so i set up a virtual host:

```
#Setup to /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf
<VirtualHost 192.168.160.128:80>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ServerName www.trangweb.world
</VirtualHost>
```

The domain is the one that root can access, but client now can access only by ip.
Somehow from client, i'm still cant access by domain name, what did i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The virtual host is set to listen for port 80 from the IP. If you set it to a * instead of IP, you will be able to access it by Domain name from anywhere.